# Insert text inside brackets via command line

Tags: parsing, sed, command

I am editing a file and want to find all occurrences of

```
\smash{example}
\smash{$example2$}
```

and replace it with

```
\smash{\small{example}}
\smash{\small{$example2$}}
```

respectively, using something like 'sed' in the command line. Any help on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it:

```
sed -r 's/(\\smash\{)([^\}]+\})/\1\\small\{\2\}/g' <filename>
```

It works as follows:

- Use `sed` to perform a replacement of text using regular expressions `sed 's/<regexp>/<replacement>/'`

  - The option `-r` allows for extended regular expressions (needed to reference to the `\1` and `\2` groups) and the `g` at the end means that the replacement should be applied to every piece of text that matches the `<regexp>`
  - The `<regexp>` pattern: `(\\smash\{)([^\}]+\})` is divided into 2 groups:

    1. `(\\smash\{)` which simply captures the first part of the string and puts it in group `\1`
    2. `([^\}]+\})` which roughly says "*read any sequence of characters til you get a `}` and put it in group 2 `\2`*"
  - Now you can use the `\1` and `\2` groups in the `<replacement>` part and insert `\\small{` in between them. Also the finishing `}` is added after group 2 is inserted.

To learn more about `sed` and `regular expressions` you might want to start off by reading these first [couple of paragraphs](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! :)

I cannot make it run using sed on my mac. I tested on a linux server and am only able to make it run using gsed not sed. Do you know how to modify the command to make it work in Sed?

Also, it seems to only work on the example \smash{\small{example}} but not on the example \smash{\small{$example2$}} where there are dollar signs included. Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks again!
Benjamin

Comment: I see; Mac's use a version of `sed` which comes from BSD. You could get the GNU version of `sed` by installing [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and then installing `gsed` using this command: `sudo port install gsed`. You should now be able to run my command.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe just replacing the `-r` with `-E` will make the command work on the Mac version of `sed`.

Comment: Thanks - it works using the -E command.
Still, I am not sure how to make it replace texts including the $ sign, e.g. replace \smash{$example2$} by \smash{\small{$example2$}}

Comment: Regarding the `$`-sign issue. Does your command include the `g` which comes after the replacement section? Without it, the replacement will only occur once instead of for all matches.

Comment: Yes I have the g and it does indeed replace it multiple places - just not in the cases where there is a $-sign...

Comment: I don't know why strings with $-signs are not replaced at your system (they work fine at mine), but you could run a second command which explicitly targets those strings: `sed -r 's/(\\smash\{)(\$[^\}]+\$\})/\1\\small\{\2\}/g' <filename>`

Comment: Hi again and thanks again! :) I found out that it is not the $-sign that is the problem, but rather that there is a / sign inside the text . This can however be fixed via your suggestion by making a second command explicitly for the /

Thanks again :)